# @RestController always return 404 when called

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two controllers (UserController and ClientController), both of the controllers are located on the same package (com.myapp.controllers.identity), and my main application file located on the parent package (com.myapp).

I create the ClientController first and it works fine. Later on, I create the UserController. When I called the UserController, it always returns 404.

Here is the snippet of my controllers' files and main application file

Application.java

```
package com.myapp;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

ClientController.java

```
package com.myapp.controllers.identity;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/identity")
@Validated
public class ClientController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/clients/{clientId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getClientByClientId(@PathVariable("clientId") String clientId) {

    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.myapp.controllers.identity;

@RestController(value = "UserController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/identity")
@Validated
public class UserController {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/users/client/:clientId")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsersByClientId(@PathVariable String clientId) 
    {

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me solve it?

Comment: maybe because of this ` "/users/client/:clientId"`

Comment: Did you try replacing `/users/client/:clientId` in the usercontroller to `/users/client/{clientId}`?

Comment: `:clientId` is a Rails-type expression and is not an RFC 6570 URL template.

Comment: (A few other notes: Use constructor injection instead of field injection. Don't specify a name for the controller. Skip `value` if it's the only item, so `@GetMapping("/users/client/{clientId}")`. Make your logger private. Just pass the class; no need to do extra stuff like `getName`. If you use Lombok, much of this can be automated with `@Slf4j @RequiredArgsConstructor`.)

Comment: One question is your clientControler is still working?

Comment: I doubt your ClientController is also throwing 404

Comment: @DupinderSingh my ClientController still working though. But yeah. its because i totally forgot about the {clientId} i forgot i am working in Java not Golang.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- thanks for the note. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple problem in your userControler, and that is `@GetMapping(value = "/users/client/:clientId")` your format of capturing parameter

this kind of parameter is not supported in spring as @chrylis -on strike- mentioned

```
package com.myapp.controllers.identity;

@RestController(value = "UserController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/identity")
@Validated
public class UserController {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{clientId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsersByClientId(@PathVariable String clientId) 
    {

    }
}
```